# can't stop submitted form from refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

The form is displayed dynamically and gives the id so I can found out which form it is coming from...

here is the php/html form

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <!-- Task Name -->
    <div><img src="{{ URL::asset('public/mealpics') }}/{{ $meal->picture }}" /></div>
    <div>{{ $meal->name }} by {{ $meal->author }}</div>
    <div>Rating: {{ $meal->rating }}</div>
    <div>Cal: {{ $meal->calories }} Fat: {{ $meal->fat }} Chol: {{ $meal->cholesterol }}</div>
    <div>Sodium: {{ $meal->sodium }} Sugar: {{ $meal->sugar }}</div>
    <div>{{ $meal->created_at }}</div>
    <div>
        <form action="/mealtrist" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="onPlan{{$meal->id}}" name="onPlan"
                   value="{{ $meal->id }}">
            <button id="submit_btn" data-mealid="{{$meal->id}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add To Plan</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $('submit_btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var diffValue = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-mealId");
        var mealId = '#onPlan' + diffValue;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo URL::to('mealtrist') ?>',
            type : 'POST',
        data : {
            onPlan: diffValue},
            });
    });
});
```

i've also tried this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var diffValue = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-mealId");
        var mealId = '#onPlan' + diffValue;
        $('#form').submit(function (e) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo URL::to('mealtrist') ?>',
                type : 'POST',
            data : $(mealId).serialize(),               success : function( response ) {
                $('#added').empty();
                $(response).appendTo("#added");
            } 
        });

        e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

i've also tried the

```
('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    ///i've even tried the e.preventDefault(); here but I think that prevents the code below from sending.
    ////code
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

none of this seems to be working. I'm using larvel 5.1 and trying to get a form to submit on a page and send the value of one input to a controller so that I can get that id and use it to store information from another table in my database. It works of course, but it also refreshes the page...that's what I'm looking for. The page turns up blank, which i understand that is happening because I'm not returning anything in my controller...that doesn't matter, because when I return the same page in my controller it still shows the page refreshing...which is what I want to get rid of. I just want the data sent through ajax so I can use it...no page refresh. I don't understand why I'm having this issue. I've read alot of other questions on here about preventing the refreshing, but none of the solutions are working. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you may look into using using Ajax.BeginForm()

Comment: After reading many times the question (and foreseeing some errors above), I'm rather here to ask you: what is the desired output? performing the ajax request and preventing the page from refreshing? if so, Just don't submit the form. Besides, the first case cannot work because `submit_btn` is not a valid ID (should be `#submit_btn` instead). Second case cannot work either, because you are preventing the form to submit and then you are submitting it manually (which is redundant). The third case won't work because there is no form with id `form` (`#form`).

Comment: Thanks...yes, I posted too quick and should have thought through some of this. I was playing around with submitting the form and preventing refresh or ajax  and left too much unnecessary code there. I ended up using ajax only.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're handling the POST yourself via ajax (your first jquery example), try changing the button from type "submit" to just type "button"

Comment: thanks...i ended up just using ajax. I thought it was less secure so i was going to try to use just the laravel framework

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`form` has no id `#form`. Try `form` instead.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sorry that was stupid of me...i meant(#form); to be something i've tried...meaning that is not what my actual code is now...i've tried putting the string 'form' and then my dynamic (id) from the meals...thanks though...sorry for misleading you

Answer (score 0):

At first set an `id` into `form` --

`<form id="MyForm" action="/mealtrist" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Then use this--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#MyForm").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();                

    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the form submit answers above. return false did not work and event.preventDefault() did not work. I also wasn't as clear in my question. I really thought it was more secure to submit my form rather than use ajax, so that is why i was trying to use the form. I ended up just using ajax to send the data.

```
        $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('.submit_btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var diffValue = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-mealId"); 
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo URL::to('meals') ?>',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                        onPlan: diffValue},
/*              success : function( response ) {
                    $('#added').empty();
                    $(response).appendTo("#added");
                } */
            });
    });
});
```

It works perfectly fine.